# Not sure if WhisperAI is using GPU

Tags: python, gpu, openai-whisper

From task manager, I can see that python is using nearly 0% GPU but around 60% CPU

I have `device = 'cuda'` in my python code and I get no errors when it runs, but it's still very slow, so I think it isn't using my GPU like it's supposed to.

```
from pytube import YouTube
import whisper

def transcribe():
    global model
    model = whisper.load_model("large", device = 'cuda')
    global audio
    audio = whisper.load_audio(f'{output_name}.mp4')
    global result
    result = model.transcribe(audio, verbose = True, language = 'Korean', task = 'translate')
```

How can I verify that WhisperAI is using my GPU?
How can I fix it if not?

Tensorflow and PyTorch are irrelevant, right? They're just separate libraries that also use GPU?

- Environment: Jupyter Notebook
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 1300
- GPU: 4095MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (MSI)
- GPU-Z States that CUDA is available on my GPU

lmk what other information you need, ty!